# How to play my Unity game in chrome extension? (unity 2022 html)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, unity-webgl

I am trying to make a simple unity game work in a google chrome extension. The build in web gl I have put it in an extension.

I have changed the html of the game so that the javascript runs in a , in the tutorial on creating extensions I saw it said that if you don't do it that way it doesn't work.

I don't know about javascript, I know about Unity.

Do I need to add something to the manifest.json?

Do I have to change the javascript?

I have not found any information on the internet about it.

I just get this message when I try to open it in a new tab or set in iframe.
[error unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7kpC.png)
[error extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBeHv.png)
Pd: yes in my build settings I have compression none

I tried make a localhost using javascript (with chat gpt) but it doesn't work fine, maybe because the extension make in sandbox idk.